# Link is displayed only when broken

Tags: html, css, styling

I will start by saying that I'm a newbie to HTML and to coding in general.
I'm having a weird issue where an hyperlink is getting displayed (as in I can see it on the screen) only when said link is broken.

While testing the site I clicked the link (it was initially visible) and it didn't send me to the address I wanted, because I had forgotten to put https:// in front of the address.

As soon as I put the prefix in though, the hyperlink wasn't visible anymore. It was still there, text showed up after it leaving a space and it now sent me to the correct address, but it wasn't displayed.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: PierSans;
  src: url(PierSans-FreeForPersonalUse/PierSans-Regular.otf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Omnes;
  src: url(Omnes/Omnes.ttf);
}

body {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-left: 11em;
  font-family: PierSans;
  color: #fcac89;
  background-color: #324a40
}

p,
address {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Omnes;
}

address a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #fcac89;
}

ul.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2em;
  left: 1em;
  width: 9em
}

ul.navbar li {
  background-color: #fcac89;
  margin: 0.5em 0em;
  padding: 0.3em;
  border-left: 0.5em solid #e38150;
}

ul.navbar li.current {
  background-color: #fcac89;
  margin: 0.5em 0em;
  padding: 0.3em;
  border-left: 0.5em solid #276359;
}

ul.navbar li:hover {
  border-left: 0.5em solid #276359;
}

ul.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.navbar a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #324a40;
}
```

```html
<!-- Navigation Bar -->
<ul class="navbar">
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li class="current"><a href="school.html">School</a></li>
  <li><a href="interests.html">My Interests</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Text here -->
<h1>School related stuff</h1>
<p>The Highschool I go to is the I.I.S. Meucci, a scientific institute located in Massa.<br> I'm currently in the fourth year of Highschool, and so next year I'll have to choose what University to go to.<br> I may choose to study subject such as Chemistry,
  IT and Mathematic, but I'm also considering more 'artistic' and 'direct' subjects like Architecture and Graphic Design.</p>
<h2>My school's contact</h2>
<address>I.I.S. Antonio Meucci Massa<br>
    <a href="https://www.iismeuccimassa.it">www.iismeuccimassa.it</a><br>
    Via Marina Vecchia, 230 54100 MASSA (MS)<br>
    Tel. 0585 252708-fax.0585 251012<br>
    msis01800l@istruzione.it<br>
    </address>
```

If someone could help me it would be appreciated, and please forgive me for my English as it isn't my first language.

Answer (score 1):

Remove a:visited from the css section.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: PierSans;
    src: url(PierSans-FreeForPersonalUse/PierSans-Regular.otf); }
@font-face {
    font-family: Omnes;
    src: url(Omnes/Omnes.ttf); }
body {
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-left: 11em;
    font-family: PierSans;
    color: #fcac89;
    background-color: #324a40 }
p, address {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Omnes; }
address a:link, a:visited {
    color: #fcac89; }
ul.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    left: 1em;
    width: 9em }
ul.navbar li {
    background-color: #fcac89;
    margin: 0.5em 0em;
    padding: 0.3em;
    border-left: 0.5em solid #e38150; }
ul.navbar li.current {
    background-color: #fcac89;
    margin: 0.5em 0em;
    padding: 0.3em;
    border-left: 0.5em solid #276359; }
ul.navbar li:hover {
    border-left: 0.5em solid #276359; }
ul.navbar a {
    text-decoration: none; }
ul.navbar a:link /* Removed a:visited from here */{
    color: #324a40; }
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="current"><a href="school.html">School</a></li>
    <li><a href="interests.html">My Interests</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Text here -->
<h1>School related stuff</h1>
<p>The Highschool I go to is the I.I.S. Meucci, a scientific institute located in Massa.<br>
I'm currently in the fourth year of Highschool, and so next year I'll have to choose what University to go to.<br>
I may choose to study subject such as Chemistry, IT and Mathematic, but I'm also considering more 'artistic' and 'direct' 
subjects like Architecture and Graphic Design.</p>
<h2>My school's contact</h2>
<address>I.I.S. Antonio Meucci Massa<br>
<a href="https://www.iismeuccimassa.it">www.iismeuccimassa.it</a><br>
Via Marina Vecchia, 230 54100 MASSA (MS)<br>
Tel. 0585 252708-fax.0585 251012<br>
msis01800l@istruzione.it<br>
</address>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following part in your CSS

```
address a:link, a:visited {
    color: #fcac89;
}
```

with this one:

```
address a:link, address a:visited {
    color: #fcac89;
}
```